# Directing email for a domain to AppEngine email receiving service?

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I'd like to have emails to a given domain, say http://mydomain.com/, processed by an AppEngine app, let's call it http://emailprocessor.appspot.com/ .

That is, an email to "hello@mydomain.com" should be received and processed by emailprocessor.appspot.com as if it was an email to "hello@emailprocessor.appspot.com" .

I imagine I could do this via MX records for my mydomain.com domain, but I can't find instructions anywhere.

Is this possible, and if so does one set it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have done is to point the MX record to a server that allows you to do email domain forwarding. Then you can forward all emails to emailprocessor.appspotmail.com.

The advantage of this is that you catch all usernames: hello@mydomain.com, goodbye@mydomain.com, etc...

If your host has cPanel see this: http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/email/email_domain_forwarding.htm

Comment: solution you offer is in other words to configure MX record. It has a huge minus - you loose control of the email. It ALL goes to the emailprocessor.appspotmail.com no exceptions! This is not what the question was.

Comment: The case I explained is what I have done to solve the Google App Engine limitation. In my case I wanted ALL emails to go through the Google Email processor.

Answer (score 4):

Also there is no direct support for this according to documentation

BUT

if your http://mydomain.com/ hosted on google apps and you create user hello@mydomain.com as gmail account and in it configure email forwarding rule to the "hello@emailprocessor.appspotmail.com" it should work as it works for any general gmail account email forwarding. It preserves original headers like sender etc.

I almost sure that most of other mail services or servers can support this feature. check documentation of your mail service.

**PAY ATTENTION! it must be emailprocessor.appspotmail.com note the appspotmail.com not appspot.com**

I did not try it myself yet so I will be happy if you confirm that this works. Again it should.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's [no documented support](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html) for receiving mail on a custom domain.

You would need to host mail elsewhere and configure a forwarder to emailprocessor.appspotmail.com.