# Forwarding All Mail Sent to a Domain (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dns, email-forwarding

I've built a Python app on Google App Engine which primarily handles incoming mail and does interesting based upon the email address at which the email is received.

I would like to use a custom domain for receiving emails as `<some text>@<my app name>.appspotmail.com` is rather cumbersome.

Unfortunately I've been unable to figure out how to get this setup. I've gleaned from questions like this one: [Custom Incoming Mail Domain With Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698802/custom-incoming-mail-domain-with-google-app-engine) that there is no way to enable this directly in Google App Engine but that using some sort of DNS trickery--probably related to MX records--that I'll be able to forward the emails sent to `<arbitrary string>@<custom domain>` to the *real* address at `<arbitrary string>@<my app name>.appspotmail.com`.

Can someone explain how to do this? I think the basic problem would be my lack of knowledge with regards to DNS, but may also be associated with the particular restrictions associated with DNS and GAE apps.

---

The solution presented in this question: [Directing email for a domain to AppEngine email receiving service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902732/directing-email-for-a-domain-to-appengine-email-receiving-service) works explicitly for domains hosted by providers with the cPanel control panel, is there a more generic solution?

Comment: see also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902732/directing-email-for-a-domain-to-appengine-email-receiving-service

Comment: @Chris W - did you ever find a generic solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing to do with "DNS trickery". You simply have to use a regular mail service - Google Apps will do - that can be configured to forward all incoming mail to a specific address, namely any address your app can receive email on. Your app can determine the original 'To' address by examining the headers.

Comment: To my understanding, Google Apps is only capable of forwarding individual, pre-specified email addresses to another email address. I need to forward *all* emails sent to a *domain*. Do you know if (and how) this can be accomplished with Google Apps?

Comment: @Chris Set up a catchall handler in the Apps admin console to forward to that single address. It's under Settings -> Email.